# checkbox values not coming in form array, angular

Tags: angular

when i select check box its value is displayed as another array and does not get updated according to the for,the userdays work only when it is outside the employee form, how do i make it work when put inside the employee form, under skills[]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cueihr

[image]

Comment: Do you want workdays to be under each group below skills? Eg.., in the above given image, do you want the userdays array to be included in all three if the add button clicked thrice??

Comment: yes, exactly that, my code is working when userdays is outside employees, but when i put it in employees array, it does not work

Comment: You could use this as reference https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-teegvs  Need to make unique control for userdays. to save the data in each individual item which now only works in first.

Comment: yea it only works for first, what do u mean by unique control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to add userdays array inside each formgroup, First create userdays array of control inside newEmployee FormGroup.

**component.ts**

```
newEmployee(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      repeat_sun: false,
      repeat_mon: false,
      repeat_tue: false,         
      skills:this.fb.array([]),
      userdays: this.fb.array([])
    })
 }
```

Then pass selected employees formGroup index from html.

```
<label class="checkbox-inline" *ngFor="let day of days; ">
    <input type="checkbox" formControlName="{{ day.name }}" name="{{ day.name }}"
        (change)="onChange(empIndex,day.value , $event.target.checked)" />{{ day.value }}
</label>
```

Finally add your logic as per your need.

**component.ts**

```
onChange(empIndex, day: string, isChecked: boolean) {
    const dayFormArray = (this.empForm.get("employees") as FormArray)
      .at(empIndex)
      .get("userdays") as FormArray;
    if (isChecked) {
      dayFormArray.push(new FormControl(day));
    } else {
      let index = (dayFormArray.value as []).findIndex(item => item === day);
      dayFormArray.removeAt(index);
    }
  }
```

[Forked Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hokbhw)

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro.. I should passed ```empIndex``` to onChange function instead of using  ```this.empForm.get("employees").value[0]``` it should be ```this.empForm.get("employees").value[empIndex]``` in the link I provided in comment section..

Comment: You are welcome bro. Yes you made small mistake sometime happens.