# How To push dynamic formGroup in Dynamic Created Form Array

Tags: angular, typescript

Actually am trying to apply reactive forms approach in my project
here in my project i have to add a **Add Season** Button and when button is clicked then a new formGroup is added with one form Control i.e **season** and one FormArray i.e **episodes** so that means **episodes** is created Dynamically now i want to add some more formGroup in **episodes** but am unable to figure out how to do that here what i have done so far:

```
export class AddContentsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {
  count = 0
  episodes = []
  ContentForm: FormGroup
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ContentForm = new FormGroup({
      'title': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'desc': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'image_url': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'subtitle_url': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'url': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'episodes': new FormArray([]),
      'seasons': new FormArray([])
    })
  }

 onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.ContentForm)
  }
addSeasons() {
while ((<FormArray>this.ContentForm.get('episodes')).length) {
      console.log('ok');
      (<FormArray>this.ContentForm.get('episodes')).removeAt((<FormArray>this.ContentForm.get('episodes')).length - 1);
    }

    (this.ContentForm.get('seasons') as any).push(new FormGroup({
      'season': new FormControl(null),
      'episodes': new FormArray([]) //here am add a dynamic formArray
    }))
  }


  DeleteSeason(index) {
    (<FormArray>this.ContentForm.get('seasons')).removeAt(index)
  }



  AddEpisodesInSeasons(index) {
    (<FormArray>this.ContentForm.get('seasons')) //now here i want to push new FormGroup to **episodes**
  }

}
```

[image]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ndnstv for more..

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ndnstv here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass selected seasons FormGroup index from html like this and add more formGroup or control as per your need.

**Try this:**

**component.html**

```
 <button type ='button' (click) = "AddEpisodesInSeasons(i)">{{'Add Episode In Season '+(i+1)}} </button>
```

**component.ts**

```
AddEpisodesInSeasons(i){
   ((this.ContentsForm.get('seasons') as FormArray).at(i).get('episodes') as FormArray).push( // here add more as you expected);
  }
```

[Forked Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-emtusw)

Comment: How can i display inputs in html i mean in formArrayName , ngFor, formGroupName what i have to fill?

Comment: Check this forked example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-emtusw

Comment: @Chellappanவ, Bro can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/60970916/7785337